# Change ajax callback button add_more

Tags: forms, hooks, ajax

a try change the **ajax** callback button but i can't, i use *hook_form_alter*()

```
function sample_hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

    $form['field_publicidad'][$language][0]['add_more']['#ajax']['callback'] = '_sample_add_more_callback'

}
```

someone can help me?

Comment: What is the actual purpose there / the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to do that when the button add_more is pressed only return me the last field as drupal returns all fields via ajax.

Comment: I did a test with the core http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.form.inc/function/field_add_more_js/7 at the end of the function add:

for ($ i = 0; $ i <$ element ['# max_delta'], $ i + +)
     unset ($ element [$ i]);

now I want to do it the right way, with a module

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for there, but remember you can set the field limit in the settings form, e.g for max 1, 2 or 3 field items.